# Ovewrite a symbolic link to your executable JAR file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I want to create or ovewrite a symbolic link to a executable JAR file:

```
 sudo ln -s /var/elcor/elCorApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/init.d/elcor
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/init.d/elcor': File exists
```

but the file already exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ln -sf`:

The `-f` or `--force` is used to update a link's target or destination.

So should be

```
sudo ln -sf /var/elcor/elCorApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/init.d/elcor
```